# Restore total file association with Visual Web Developer 2008?

Tags: windows, dreamweaver, visual-web-developer, file-association

Is this possible? I installed Dreamweaver to take advantage of some third party plugin to make special xml files but upon installing it, it took over all my ASP.NET file types (even though I clicked 'select none' on the pop-up at first start). Anyways does anyone know if there is a quick automated way to restore them to Visual Web Developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is int he Express version, but VS2008 has a "Restore File Associations" button on the Tools/Options.../Environment/General property page.

If that isn't there in Express, I'd try performing a 'repair' install.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859) is the only way to do it. Sadly you will have to do it for every file types you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Repair the installation?

Answer (score 0):

In VS go to tools-option-enviroment-general and click restore file associations button. :)